# Wifi driver is not installing and wifi is not working

Tags: 12.04

I have made dual booting with windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have hp pavilion g6 2102tx laptop. Internet through lan wire is working fine but wifi is not turning on and is not connecting to any network. I have tried some of solutions written but they are in vain. Someone please help me as i my college i have to work with ubuntu and there only wifi are available.

Answer (score 1):

You can try opening "Software Sources", or "Software and Updates" from the dash. Then, go to the "Additional Drivers" or "Proprietary Drivers" tab, and see if you can enable the driver your wireless card there.

If that doesn't work, try installing the appropriate driver for your computer's wireless card from the list here http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers.